# Magento Admin CSS and JS paths incorrect after moving server and product pages empty?

Tags: magento, admin

I have recently moved a Magento site from a subdomain to it's destination domain at picnprint.me on a different server. I am experiencing two problems at the moment since moving the site to the new server.

The admin area CSS and JS paths are being rendered incorrectly.
For example... The Magento Admin page is looking for adminhtml/default/default/reset.css instead of picnprint.me/skin/adminhtml/default/default/…

If I place the CSS and JS files in the locations that the admin pages are currently pathing to then the Magento Admin will load normally but won't allow me to login.

Also, All the product pages on the front end are displaying blank, the site template loads but no product content loads.
Does anyone know what the cause of these issues could be and how I remedy the problem?

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 22):

Using your favourite RDMS tool (such as phpMyAdmin) open the table `core_config_data`, correct the values for the paths `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`. Make sure `dev/js/merge_files` and `dev/css/merge_css_files` are both 0.

Clear the cache by deleting all files in `var/cache/` in your Magento directory.

Comment: Yep, both web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url are updated to the new url. Both dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_css_files didn't exist in the core_config_data table so I have added them but no effect unfortunately.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after adding a module which calmed to merge and minifying my CSS and JS, I've fully disabled the module but not magento is still using the wrong CSS. Checked all those DB fields, and they are correct. Deleted var/cache still no luck. Finally I tried the answer below but apache already have access to media. Does anyone have anything else to fix this I'm going mad! - Thanks

Comment: Depending on how the store was set up the cache could actually be in the database, empty the tables `core_cache` and `core_cache_tag`. Also try [disabling compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538415/471559).

Comment: Thanks for the input @clockworkgeek . It actually turned out to be a syntax error inside my layout.xml obviously the css and js settings were not being set.

Comment: Had the same problem. Disabling the merge fixed it

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I know this may not be the answer to the above question but still feel that this could help someone with a very similar issue.

I have had this problem a couple of times now and end up googling in circles for 20 minutes before I remember the solution. This post is mostly for my future self who will undoubtedly have the issue again.

I had 'combine javascript and css enabled'. My locally combined css and js files were being automatically deployed to the server.

The issue was that my `media` folder where all the css and js was now being loaded from did not have the correct permissions. After granting apache write permission all of my troubles went away :).

It is probably a good idea to add the `media/css` and `media/js` folders to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Solved my problem exactly. Thanks for taking the time to add your input.