# Magento CSS & JS Paths Incorrect After Server Move - Tried Clearing Cache

Tags: magento

I'm having a strange problem with a server move. We've recently moved from a development server to the live sever with a website. However upon moving to our new server domain.com, we've developed an issue.

Basically the CSS and the JS aren't loading. Looking at the source code, the issue is clear - no trailing slash at the end of domains, so for example, the favicon URL is this:-

http://domain.commedia/favicon/default/favicon.gif

A google search threw this issue up - [Magento Admin CSS and JS paths incorrect after moving server and product pages empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324178/magento-admin-css-and-js-paths-incorrect-after-moving-server-and-product-pages-e) - and, whilst I've followed these steps, there is still the issue.

Any suggestions will be greatfully appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if Magento has created a tmp directory (as the base url had the trailing slash missing initially). it may be using a tmp cache there, delete it if that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Are you 100% sure that your `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` configurations are correct?  Make sure your new site (on the new host) is connecting to the correct database (look in `app/etc/local.xml`), and verify these values directly in the `core_config` table.  Your urls should have a trailing forward slash `/`, like `http://domain.com/`
2. If you can access the Magento admin, disable all caching under `System > Cache Management`
3. Are you using memcached on the new server?  Try restarting the `memcached` service using shell: `service memcached restart` as it can cache Magento configurations.
4. Make sure you delete everything under `var/cache`, and double check that it was deleted.
5. Disable all 3rd party extensions.  They could be affecting the path of your CSS files.  you can disable them by removing the XML files under `app/etc/modules`

Comment: Wasn't quite right, but managed to find the issue.

There were a bunch of caching folders on the site, removing one associated with WordPress, and it worked. Cheers guys :)

Comment: I wish you mentioned the caching directories.

Comment: @Mohit - I did...  It's `var/cache` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Axel Sorry Axel. I must have missed. Thanks.