# magento is not open correctly after install

Tags: php, magento, xampp, wampserver, magento-1.8

I am trying to install magento on localhost and it installed correctly. but after that it is not open in correct view. i am trying in both wamp and xamp  server but getting same result.

it is open in this view

[image]

i thought it is due to curl problem, but curl is already enabled.

```
  extension=php_bz2.dll
  extension=php_curl.dll
  extension=php_mbstring.dll
  extension=php_exif.dll
  ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
  extension=php_gd2.dll
  extension=php_gettext.dll
  ;extension=php_gmp.dll
   ;extension=php_intl.dll
```

please tell me , what should i  do to correct this.

Comment: try `clearing the cache, rebuilding index and running compilation process form the backend and also try deleting the 'var' folder in your magento installation`....

Comment: i did this, but same result

Comment: And  this problem is same in backhand also

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324178/magento-admin-css-and-js-paths-incorrect-after-moving-server-and-product-pages-e

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a problem with your base url. Make sure your base url has '/' in the end. `eg, http://localhost/myMagentoInstallation/` . To change go to your database, search for `core_config_data table` and change both the secure and unsecure base url.

You can Inspect element, and check the path for the js and css pages. I think the installation cannot find js or css files due to incorrect format of the base url.

Comment: how can i check the path of js and css page?

Comment: In your browser, right click and either do "Inspect Element" or "View Page Source", which will provide you the html source for the current rendered page. Then in the <head> portion, u'll see the links for the css/js files. Btw, if u are using linux, make sure you have read permission for skin folder in the magento root installation.

Comment: yes , i saw, but all the path of link are correct, and i am using window

Comment: Select the path once, and see if you can access it in browser, if you can then clear the Magento cache, and you should be ready to go. Your magento installaton went fine if you can access the page.

Comment: path is working in browser and i cleared cache also, but still facing same problem